# ¿Como guardar las coordenadas de un circle de google maps en la base de datos?

Tags: android, php, mysql, google-maps

Como puedo guardar las coordenadas de un circle de google maps en la base de datos, ya cargue el mapa y con la funcion onMapLongClickListener permite dibujar un nuevo circle al usuario.
Ahora lo que me gustaria hacer es poder almacenar esos valores. Y hasta ahora no encontre ningun link que me ayude

Comment: ¿que tal si agregas un campo en la base y almacenas alli el radio del circulo? si quieres volver a crearlo, consultas la base y utilizas el radio que almacenaste anteriormente.

Answer (score 2):

De esta manera se crea un circle en el google map api v3 de Android. Suponiendo que ya sabes comunicarte con tu base de datos.

```
Circle circle = map.addCircle(new CircleOptions()
     .center(new LatLng(-33.87365, 151.20689))
     .radius(10000)
     .strokeColor(Color.RED)
     .fillColor(Color.BLUE));
```

Como puedes ver tienes los siguientes valores a guardar para poder volver a dibujar el circle: `new LatLng(-33.87365, 151.20689)` y el `radius(1000)`.

Por lo tanto guardaras los siguientes tres elementos del circulo captado por el usuario en tu Base de datos.

```
double latitud = circle.getCenter().latitude;
double longitud = circle.getCenter().longitude;
double radio = circle.getRadius();

guardarCircleEnBaseDeDatos(latitud,longitud,radio);
```

Posterior mente como vimos en el comienzo podrás dibujar los circulos con sus coordenadas y su radio.

```
    //Creas un objeto circulo de una clase creada previamente por ti para facilitar el trabajo.
    Circulo circulo = ObtenerCirculoDeBD();

    double latitud = circulo.getLatitud();
    double longitud = circulo.getLongitud();
    double radio = circulo.getRadio();

    Circle miCirculoDeLaBD = map.addCircle(new CircleOptions()
             .center(new LatLng(latitud , longitud))
             .radius(radio)
             .strokeColor(Color.RED)
             .fillColor(Color.BLUE));
```

> Te dejo la documentación,
>   https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/maps/model/Circle.